# Default IEqualityComparer for TDictionary<TObject, TObject>?

Tags: performance, delphi, generics, tdictionary

I just read

> "Any class that implements the
>   IEqualityComparer interface is
>   expected to provide the implementation
>   for the **Equals** method." - ([Delphi
>   DocWiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Generics.Defaults.IEqualityComparer.Equals))

and

> "Any class that implements the
>   IEqualityComparer interface is
>   expected to provide the implementation
>   for the **GetHashCode** method." -
>   ([Delphi DocWiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Generics.Defaults.IEqualityComparer.GetHashCode))

How will performance of a TDictionary be if I create a `TDictionary<TObject, TObject>` and do not implement a IEqualityComparer?

I have not found a default implementation (in Delphi 2009). So how will the hash code for they keys be calculated?

If it is simply the memory address of the object in the Dictionary entries key, will a search for a given entry be performed in sequential order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default implementation will perform extremely well with a TObject key.  Equality is defined to be object identity, the same as testing `if A=B`. The hash is simply the address of the reference – it could not be more efficient.

The code looks like this:

```
function TObject.Equals(Obj: TObject): Boolean;
begin
  Result := Obj = Self;
end;

function TObject.GetHashCode: Integer;
begin
  Result := Integer(Self);
end;
```

Looking up in a hashed dictionary does not involve searching. It is a highly efficient O(1) operation. I think you should take a read of the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) article.

Comment: Delphi could have added Equals and GetHashCode as new methods in the TObject class instead of introducing the IEqualityComparer interface, maybe

Comment: @mjn Not everything that can be put in a TDictionary descends from TObject, so to force you to use TObject would have crippled it in my view. Could not use strings, GUIDs etc.

Comment: Oh, I forgot - right, there is no String, or GUID class in Delphi.

Comment: What does "Looking up in a hashed dictionary does not involve searching." mean? The article in Wikipedia mentions content addressable memory ...

Comment: @mjn It's all there in that article. You asked if a lookup involved sequential search. It doesn't. It's an O(1) operation. For linear search the expected time to retrieve a value increases as the container size increases. That is not the case for a hash.

Comment: Doesn't it depend on the quality of the hash function? (reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)

Comment: @mjn Hash function for TObject cannot really be improved upon.

Comment: Now I understand :) TObject was an example - actually I meant any TObject subclass (no basic data types like string)

Comment: This trick is not going to work with 64bit Delphi. Maybe we'll have NativeInt sized hashes there?

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick For 64 bit the `GetHashCode` is implemented as `Result := Integer(IntPtr(Self)) xor Integer(IntPtr(Self) shr 32);` not quite as efficient as the 32 bit code - but still pretty fast.